# How to use custom confirmation message with kendo ui grid destroy command?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, command, kendo-grid, destroy, confirmation

I am working on the ASP.NET MVC4 application with the Kendo UI Grid.

And I want to show a custom confirmation message with Destroy command instead of the usual confirmation message.

Below is the piece of code for that:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Gts.Core.Dto.CategoryDto>().Columns(columns =>
       {columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(70).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "text-align:right;padding:0px;" });
}).DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.CategoryID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("CategoryItemDetails", "Category", new { CategoryID = "#=CategoryID#", categoryId = "#=FKCategoryID#" }))
                        .Destroy(update => update.Action("CategoryDestroy", "Category"))
             )
            .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBoundChild").Edit("dataBoundEdit").Remove("deleteCategoryChild").Save("datasourceChange")).ToClientTemplate()
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom template column like the below one

```
{ command: { text: "Delete", click: deleteData }, title: "Delete", width: width7, menu: false }
```

and inside deleteData function you can show a custom user friendly message in a confirm box.